# Connecting nodes in a proper way

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, fun

How can I connect the $n$-th node with the $n-1$ node?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    io/.style={
        fill=black,circle,inner sep=.1pt
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,10,...,350}
            {
%               \draw[rotate around={(-\x:(-\x:1))}] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (.5,1) -- (.5,0) arc(0:-180:.25);
                    \node[rotate around={(\x:(\x:1))},io] {};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \node[rotate around={(-\x:(4*\x:1))},io] {};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{cos(\x)*\x}
                    \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] {};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{12*\x}
                    \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                        \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\x^sin(\x)}
                    \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                        \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\x^cos(\x)}
                    \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                        \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\x^sin(2*\x)}
                    \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                        \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{17*\x}
                    \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                        \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is an answer for your first picture, which works for all your pictures.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    io/.style={
        fill=black,circle,inner sep=.1pt
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x [count=\n] in {0,10,...,350}
            {
%               \draw[rotate around={(-\x:(-\x:1))}] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (.5,1) -- (.5,0) arc(0:-180:.25);
                    \node[rotate around={(\x:(\x:1))},io] (io-\n) {};
                    \ifnum\n>1
                      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevn}{\n-1}
                      \draw (io-\prevn) -- (io-\n);
                    \fi
                    \xdef\nmax{\n}
            }
        \draw (io-\nmax) -- (io-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the full thing.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    io/.style={
        fill=black,circle,inner sep=.1pt
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x [count=\n] in {0,10,...,350}
            {
%               \draw[rotate around={(-\x:(-\x:1))}] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (.5,1) -- (.5,0) arc(0:-180:.25);
                    \node[rotate around={(\x:(\x:1))},io] (io-\n) {};
                    \ifnum\n>1
                      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevn}{\n-1}
                      \draw (io-\prevn) -- (io-\n);
                    \fi
                    \xdef\nmax{\n}
            }
        \draw (io-\nmax) -- (io-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \node[rotate around={(-\x:(4*\x:1))},io] (io-\x) {};
                \ifnum\x>0
                  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevx}{\x-1}
                  \draw (io-\prevx) -- (io-\x);
                \fi
                \xdef\xmax{\x}
            }
        \draw (io-\xmax) -- (io-0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{cos(\x)*\x}
                \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (io-\x) {};
                \ifnum\x>0
                  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevx}{\x-1}
                  \draw (io-\prevx) -- (io-\x);
                \fi
                \xdef\xmax{\x}
            }
        \draw (io-\xmax) -- (io-0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{12*\x}
                \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
                \ifnum\x>0
                  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevx}{\x-1}
                  \draw (\prevx) -- (\x);
                \fi
                \xdef\xmax{\x}
            }
        \draw (\xmax) -- (0);   
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\x^sin(\x)}
                \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
                \ifnum\x>0
                  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevx}{\x-1}
                  \draw (\prevx) -- (\x);
                \fi
                \xdef\xmax{\x}
            }
        \draw (\xmax) -- (0);   
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\x^cos(\x)}
                \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
                \ifnum\x>0
                  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevx}{\x-1}
                  \draw (\prevx) -- (\x);
                \fi
                \xdef\xmax{\x}
            }
        \draw (\xmax) -- (0);   
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\x^sin(2*\x)}
                \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
                \ifnum\x>0
                  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevx}{\x-1}
                  \draw (\prevx) -- (\x);
                \fi
                \xdef\xmax{\x}
            }
        \draw (\xmax) -- (0);   
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{17*\x}
                \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
                \ifnum\x>0
                  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevx}{\x-1}
                  \draw (\prevx) -- (\x);
                \fi
                \xdef\xmax{\x}
            }
        \draw (\xmax) -- (0);   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Very pretty! With much simpler diagrams than yours I label the nodes and remember the labels using code like:

```
\foreach \x [remember=\x as \X] in {0,10,...,350}
{
    \node[rotate around={(\x:(\x:1))},io](\x) {};
     \ifnum\x>0\draw(\X)--(\x);\fi
 }
```

The `remember=\x as \X` stores the last value of the node label `(\x)` and then I use `\ifnum` to make sure that I am at the second or later label. Using this, your first diagram becomes:

[image]

If you want to join up the first and last coordinate then it is enough to add:

```
\draw(350)--(0);
```

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    io/.style={
        fill=black,circle,inner sep=.1pt
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x [remember=\x as \X] in {0,10,...,350}
            {
%               \draw[rotate around={(-\x:(-\x:1))}] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (.5,1) -- (.5,0) arc(0:-180:.25);
                    \node[rotate around={(\x:(\x:1))},io](\x) {};
                    \ifnum\x>0\draw(\X)--(\x);\fi
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x [remember=\x as \X] in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \node[rotate around={(-\x:(4*\x:1))},io] (\x){};
                    \ifnum\x>0\draw(\X)--(\x);\fi
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x [remember=\x as \X] in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{cos(\x)*\x}
                    \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x){};
                    \ifnum\x>0\draw(\X)--(\x);\fi
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x [remember=\x as \X] in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{12*\x}
                    \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                        \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
                    \ifnum\x>0\draw(\X)--(\x);\fi
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x [remember=\x as \X] in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\x^sin(\x)}
                    \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                        \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
                    \ifnum\x>0\draw(\X)--(\x);\fi
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x [remember=\x as \X] in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\x^cos(\x)}
                    \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                        \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
                    \ifnum\x>0\draw(\X)--(\x);\fi
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x [remember=\x as \X] in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\x^sin(2*\x)}
                    \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                        \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
                    \ifnum\x>0\draw(\X)--(\x);\fi
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \foreach \x [remember=\x as \X] in {0,1,...,359}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{17*\x}
                    \draw[ultra thin] ([rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))}]0,0) -- (0,0);
                        \node[rotate around={(-\x:(\a:1))},io] (\x) {};
                    \ifnum\x>0\draw(\X)--(\x);\fi
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```